# Altair chart not displaying when evaluated within a function

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, jupyter-lab, altair

The following code, taken from the Altair [docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/weather_heatmap.html), correctly displays in my Jupyter Lab notebook.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.seattle_temps.url

alt.Chart(
    source,
    title="2010 Daily High Temperature (F) in Seattle, WA"
).mark_rect().encode(
    x='date(date):O',
    y='month(date):O',
    color=alt.Color('max(temp):Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme="inferno")),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip('monthdate(date):T', title='Date'),
        alt.Tooltip('max(temp):Q', title='Max Temp')
    ]
).properties(width=550)
```

[image]

However, if I cut and paste that exact code in a function, and then call the function, the chart no longer displays.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

def visualize():
    source = data.seattle_temps.url
    alt.Chart(
        source,
        title="2010 Daily High Temperature (F) in Seattle, WA"
    ).mark_rect().encode(
        x='date(date):O',
        y='month(date):O',
        color=alt.Color('max(temp):Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme="inferno")),
        tooltip=[
            alt.Tooltip('monthdate(date):T', title='Date'),
            alt.Tooltip('max(temp):Q', title='Max Temp')
        ]
    ).properties(width=550)
    
visualize()
```

I read through Altair's [display troubleshooting](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html) docs, and it seems the most common fix for this specific issue is to ensure that the chart is evaluated, which it is in this case. I'm not writing `chart = alt.Chart(...)`, I'm skipping the assignment and going straight to the evaluation, which is why it worked outside of the function.

Why bother with the function? The reason I want to wrap it in a function is that I have a huge dataset (100 GBs) stored in a database. When I specify a filter to the database, the result is only 600 rows, so very manageable. I want to put this in a Jupyter Lab notebook and make the filter interative for non-technical users, so I created ipython widget for specifying the filter value. When a user specifies a filter in the widget, the widget needs a callback function to trigger the read from the database and produce the visual on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your function is not returning anything. You are creating the chart, but not returning it so that the Jupyter Notebook can render it. If you write `return alt.Chart(...` it will work. If you don't want to return anything you can also append `.display()` to the chart spec inside the function (this also works for displaying charts in loops).